# How to push a commit with a complete replacement?

Tags: git

I started to work with a whole new version of my project. I created a new project in my IDE, I did `git init`, then I added my remote. But now I want to commit this without destroying the current history, so `git push --force` is not an option. Is it possible to just push a new commit replacing the old project on remote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to pull your repository into a clean folder, remove everything and add the new code:

```
git clone <your_remote> <optional directory name>
cd <cloned dir>
git rm -r *
cp -r /path/to/new/code/* .
git add .
git commit -m"Redid everything!"
git push
```

If you are sure everything is OK you can delete the copy of the new code. **A better idea in my opinion** if you want both revisions in the same place, is to branch off from the initial commit (after you cd'd to the clone dir):

```
git checkout <first empty commit>
git checkout -B my_redo_version
```

then continue from the `cp` line. This also has the benefit that you can use your existing folder you `init`'d - just stash your code, pull the master branch, checkout the first commit, branch off, and pop.

Comment: This is a smart solution. I thought there is a simpler and automatic way to achieve this. Thank you!